# How can I add a namespace to Symfony 2.1?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.1

I have a 3rd party lib using namespaces I would like to add to the vendor directory. For certain reasons I can't use composer for this lib. Adding it using the add method of ClassLoader does not work for me ("class not found"). In Detail:

I am using Symfony 2.1.7.

```
// app/autoload.php
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry;
$loader = require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
$loader->add('Example', realpath(__DIR__.'/../vendor/example/src'));
AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader(array($loader, 'loadClass'));
return $loader;
```

Directory structure in the vendor directory:

[image: directory structure]

```
//vendor/example/src/Foo.php
namespace Example;
class Foo {

}
```

Using it in my controller:

```
 $bar = new \Example\Foo();
```

Result:

> Class 'Example\Foo' not found

Where is my mistake? And/or: What's the best way to debug this issue in Symfony 2.1?

Comment: Not sure about symphony but most probably you may try this `use vendor/example/src/Foo.php` before you instantiate it using `$bar = new \Example\Foo();`.

Comment: @SheikhHeera won't work without to define the namespace in the autoloader.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The directory structure is wrong. Both UniversalClassLoader (used in Symfony < 2.1) and Composer's ClassLoader (used in Symfony 2.1) implement the PSR-0 autoloader standard.  This standard requires that the files with the namespaces cannot be in the root directory, and must be created under a minimum of one directory.

This worked for me:

Directory structure
[image: working directory structure]

// in autoload.php

```
// Symfony 2.1 using Composer's ClassLoader
$loader->add('Example', realpath(__DIR__.'/../vendor/example/example/src'));
```

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks!  I needed this for the symblog tutorial.  The two lines I added were: `$loader->add('Enquiry', realpath(__DIR__.'/../src/Blogger/BlogBundle/Entity'));
$loader->add('EnquiryType', realpath(__DIR__.'/../src/Blogger/BlogBundle/Form'));
`

Answer (score 0):

You have different options:

Register the namespace in your actual autoloader.

Register your namespace in app/autoload.php. You can see an example of that here https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/2.0/app/autoload.php#L9

Add the library to the PHP include_path

Add the namespace to composer (you can add custom namespaces in your composer.json even if the library doesn't have composer.json)

Comment: They changed adding namespaces from 2.0 to 2.1 as now Composer's ClassLoader is used, so the old "registerNamespaces" method does not work in 2.1 anymore. That's why I used the add() method in my example code.

Comment: You are having a mistake here. There is no registerNamespaces in ../vendor/autoload.php but the method exists in UniveralClassLoader. Just create the loader and register it. You can have more than one loader enable at the same time

Comment: finally figured it out, the directory structure was wrong (see my answer below). Thanks anyway! :-)

Answer (score 0):

In the following file you will see some namespaces listed. You can add yours in the same manner:

```
// approot/vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php

return array(
    'Twig_Extensions_' => $vendorDir . '/twig/extensions/lib/', 
    ....
    ....
    '' => $baseDir . '/src/',
);
```