# How to add custome bundles in symfony which are hosted locally?

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, symfony-2.3, autoloader

Let's assume, I made a custom symfony bundle like a small ORM, and now I want to include this bundle and register it in the `AppKernel` currently, the bundle in found in the Vendor folder. So, what I did primary is add it in the kernel

```
new Virka\ORMBundle\VirkaORMBundle(),
```

then I tried to add it, in the autoloader like this:

```
$loader->add('Virka',__DIR__.'/../vendor/VirkaORMBundle()');
```

Now, symfony gives me an error saying,

```
FatalErrorException: Error: Class 'Virka\ORMBundle\VirkaORMBundle' not found in C:\wamp\www\Symfony\app\AppKernel.php line 20
```

Obviously, line 20 is `new Virka\ORMBundle\VirkaORMBundle(),` I have tried every thing, but it just won't work. And, I want to be able to do this without uploading the bundle to github or pacakgist.

So, How do I would like help from you, 
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete the `parantheses ()` :

```
$loader->add( 'YOURNAMESPACE', __DIR__.'/../vendor/YOURBUNDLEDIR/' );
```

**Edit :**

`YOURNAMESPACE` : the namespace to use in `use statements`

`YOURBUNDLEDIR` : the folder in your file system which contains the class `VirkaORMBundle()`

[This link may help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14911842/how-can-i-add-a-namespace-to-symfony-2-1)

Comment: I removed the `()` from `VirkaORMBundle()` and still the same result

Answer (score 1):

Do you use composer? If so, you have to add your namespace in the `vendor/composer/autoload_namespace.php` file.