# Attempted to load class "ClassName" from namespace (...). Even though namespace is imported

Tags: php, symfony, namespaces

I have a Symfony project to which I added some non-symfony php files containing various classes. But for some reason the classes are not loaded when loading the website, even though the IDE sees them properly.

So, I have a class that needs other classes:

```
namespace rootspace\FrontBundle\Controller;

use rootspace\FrontBundle\Networks\TwitterOAuth;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;

class TwitterController extends Controller
{
    public function connectAction(){
        // The TwitterOAuth instance
        $connection = new TwitterOAuth('abc', '123');
    }
}
```

And then the class which fails to load (that needs yet another file)

```
namespace rootspace\FrontBundle\Networks;

/* Load OAuth lib. You can find it at http://oauth.net */
//require_once('OAuth.php'); -- should this be commented out?

/**
 * Twitter OAuth class
 */
class TwitterOAuth {
  /* Contains the last HTTP status code returned. */
}
```

Lastly, the third file

```
namespace rootspace\FrontBundle\Networks;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\Exception;

class OAuthConsumer
{
    public $key;
    public $secret;
}
(...)
```

I assume the actual filenames don't matter, right? Nor their structure? PhpStorm sees all the classes properly, I can right-click through them, but it fails when deployed.

Thanks for help

Edit - the whole error message says

```
Attempted to load class "TwitterOAuth" from namespace "rootspace\FrontBundle\Networks" in D:\Dropbox\project\src\rootspace\FrontBundle\Controller\TwitterController.php line 15. Do you need to "use" it from another namespace?
```

Comment: Do you use composer?

Comment: For autoloading, filenames need to match class names.  Can you post your error message?

Comment: Yeah, I use composer. But I did not use it for creation of the classes. Should I? I am new to PHP :|

So does this mean that I need to have only one class in one file? The TwitterOAuth class is in a file of the same name, but it contains more classes. The OAuthConsumer is in file OAuth.php.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because Symfony's autoloader follows `PSR` standards ([PSR-0](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/), [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/)) which says that fully qualified (with namespace) class name translates to file location and name. So in fact file names **does matter**. 
So in your case `rootspace\FrontBundle\Networks\TwitterOAuth` class should be located in `rootspace/FrontBundle/Networks` directory in file called `TwitterOAuth.php`

If classes you are using does not follow `PSR` standards you can also register them manually in `app/autoloader.php` file

Check these for more info:

[How can I add a namespace to Symfony 2.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14911842/how-can-i-add-a-namespace-to-symfony-2-1):

[How to autoload class](https://test-sf-doc-es.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook/tools/autoloader.html)

And check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12746414/2393077) answer

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add a .php extension to my filename